# flutter android MissingPluginException

Tags: android, flutter

[  +17 ms] E/flutter (16290): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method showToast on
channel PonnamKarthik/fluttertoast)
this error happens with several packages on android ios works fine
I have tried flutter clean but still not working
and I have another app with the same packages that works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

1. check your pubspec.yaml file and make sure you have proper indentation for the fluttertoast dependency.
2. clean flutter project using flutter clean and then run flutter pub get in command line/Terminal
3. then try building the project again. It should work as your expectation.

Thanks.

Comment: i have tried all the above but still not working and I also have a wired issue I'm not using shared_preferences and it gives me the same error on shared preferences.  MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)

Comment: can you share the screenshots of pubspec.yaml file and where and how you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling the app from the device, then use flutter clean, finally run the code again. Sometimes the updated pubspec doesn't reflect in the device unless app is reinstalled

Answer (score 0):

It solved i was forgot to add facebook configurations